# How to correctly position LinearLayout with ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this code in my fragment layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.app.MainFragment">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorDivider">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.91"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/btmedtext"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:hint="Send message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </EditText>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is :

[image]

My question is : how to avoid this floating LinearLayout (EditText + FloatingActionButton) over the Recyclerview ?
I want to keep this LinearLayout at the bottom and when the EditText is used, the ScrollView should jump up of it.

[image]

Comment: Try adding the align_parentBottom = "true" or layout_below=@id/list

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The views can not even show with each other

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when using a floating action button, it seems your only choices are to either move the button entirely, hide the button or you could add an empty container at the end dynamically, thus moving the blocked content up.

Check out [THIS](https://github.com/telly/FloatingAction) library. You could utilize this if the moving or empty container are out of the question. It allows you to keep your button and present it when needed.

[image: Floating Action Button Hide Library]

Comment: Thank u, i will view this library. By the way, check my update to see the picture from WhatsApp chat, that's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.app.MainFragment">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorDivider">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editbox_laypou"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:id="@+id/editbox_laypou">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.91"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="Send message"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
            </EditText>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/button_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```